# Using a dictionary when the Key and the Value are the same?

Tags: .net, collections, string

I want to hold about 30 strings in a static "collection". I then need to check the path of an incoming web request against this list.

I was thinking of using a StringDictionary with the Key and the Value having the the same values. However it just seems odd when all I really want is a key look up, so I can check for existence rather than look up a value to use.

Am I worrying about nothing?

Pat

Comment: What language are you talking about? Not that it's terribly relevant to your question, but you seem to use language-specific vocabulary.

Comment: StringDictionary is .NET, but appears to be not in Java

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What language are you using?

.NET supports [Hashset<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx), which fits what you're describing.

Comment: I am using C#\.NET 3.5. I had never even heard of HashSet<>, thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you just need a key lookup to check for existence, use a Set instead.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the comments about this being what a set is for - but it's also the case that prior to version 3.5, .NET didn't *have* a set type. The closest you could easily get (using just the built-in libraries and not writing your own set) was a dictionary where the value is irrelevant.

However, I wonder whether for just 30 strings in .NET earlier than 3.5, a `List<string>` might not be the ticket. We know that hashsets work really well for *big* sets, but *if* you know you're using a small set of strings, a simple `List<string>.Contains` call will be fairly quick. `String.Equals` can check lengths to start with, and then check each character so it's probably going to reject non-matches very quickly.

In short, I'd probably use `HashSet<string>` if you're using .NET 3.5, `List<string>` if you're using .NET 2.0 or 3.0, and possibly `ArrayList` if you're using .NET 1.1. That should give the simplest possible calling code, and the performance is likely to be fine. If you believe it's becoming a bottleneck, prove it with a profiler.